# Adjustwidth in two-column layout?

Tags: koma-script, two-column, geometry, layout, changepage

Is it possible to change the *outer* margin of a two-column layout mid-document? You see that in the following, it's always the left margin that's increased. However, I'd like to inrease the left margin in a left column and the right margin in a right column. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{changepage, lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[2-4]
    \end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: using multicol is probably not an option, as the document should contain floats.

Answer (score 2):

In general LaTeX sets text paragraph by paragraph and only afterwards possibly starts a new page within the paragraph. Crudely, the setting for a paragraph continues across a page boundary.

An `adjustwidth` environment will be constant across a page boundary. For `twocolumns` the setting will continue from one column to the next. You can have two different settings for left and right columns but if a columnbreak occurs in the middle of a column the setting will continue for that paragraph on to the next column.

However, you can have different settings in the two columns.

```
% adjtwocolprob.tex  SE 639945
%% from SE 640138
%% DG with multicol \docolaction{left}{middle}{right}
%% John Kormylo  \if@firstcolumn, but not reliable
    
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{changepage, lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{altadjustwidth}[2]{%
  \if@firstcolumn
  \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}
    \else
    \begin{adjustwidth}{#2}{#1}
      \fi}
{\end{adjustwidth}}
  
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \lipsum[5]

    \begin{center}
    TRY IT WITH ALTADJUSTWIDTH
    \end{center}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{altadjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{altadjustwidth}
    \begin{altadjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{altadjustwidth}
    \begin{altadjustwidth}{1cm}{0cm}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{altadjustwidth}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it is up to you to make sure that an `adjustwith` does not cross a page boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{changepage, lipsum,multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols} 
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OK, what I didn't say is that I am trying this to solve some interaction issue between margins and floats.