# With twocolumns is there a macro which tells you which column is being typeset?

Tags: two-column, multicol

Apologies for not providing an MWE, but my use case is along the lines of

```
\newenvironment{...}{
  \if in first column then put something in left margin
  \else put something else in right margin
  \fi
}{}
```

Comment: like page numbers this can only be detected in the output routine, so you would need some label.

Comment: If you are using the package `multicol` (as the tag suggests), you could use `\docolaction{left}{middle}{right}`

Comment: There is `\if@firstcolumn`, although it is not reliable.  Specifically, not in a paragraph which is split across two columns.  It will tell you whether it was in the first column when the paragraph was created.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I used your `\If@firstcolumn` suggestion in my answer ro https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639945